# Appium on Android : assert object properties (focused, enabled, ...)

Tags: java, automated-tests, appium, appium-android

I'm experimenting with [Appium](https://appium.io) to automate tests on Android app and would like to write an assertion about the current state of a particular object.

As an example, let's say that I have a [MobileElement](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/MobileElement.html) instance and I would like to assert that this element is currently focused.

I tried to use `getAttribute` :

```
mobileElement.getAttribute("focus")
```

but this call throws `org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException` exception. (probably because mobileElement is an [AndroidElement](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/android/AndroidElement.html))

Is it possible to retrieve state/attributes/properties of a AndroidElement with Appium/JsonWireProtocol or is there an extension implementing it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can [Get Active Element](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/other/active/) and compare its [Id](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebElement.html#getId--) with the element you previously found, if the Ids are the same - it means that the element you've found is the active element.

Example code:

```
MobileElement someElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//"));
MobileElement currentElement = (MobileElement) driver.switchTo().activeElement();

if (someElement.getId().equals(currentElement.getId())) {
    System.out.println("someElement is the current one");
}
```

You might also be interested in [SeeTest Appium Extension](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/SeeTest+-+Appium+Extension) which provides extra [Element Commands](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Element+Commands) on top of Appium